# Does CRYSTAL_WORKERS defaulting to 4 seem too low for a Crystal-lang app? Anyone else benchmark higher?

Tags: parallel-processing, benchmarking, crystal-lang, fibers

I am very happy that Crystal-lang now has multithreading. Has anyone else done some multi-threaded benchmarking for Crystal-lang; if so, what CRYSTAL_WORKERS have you seen to be beneficial for what you benchmarked? (Yeah, I know, every benchmark is different, so mileage may vary.)

The default for CRYSTAL_WORKERS is 4, but it seems like it should be more, at least on higher-core systems. Could the benchmarks that lead to that `4` value possibly be tied to a side-effect of the number of cores used at the time or something else?

- https://crystal-lang.org/2019/09/06/parallelism-in-crystal.html
- https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/commit/f106d93f9bc10a0176d2da6f07f477ad34a9cda4#diff-390767d4904eb70109bd332570d8cc4R216

I did some Fibonacci comparisons on an 8-core (Intel) and a 16-core (AMD) CPU and got some large peaks and valley patterns ( https://github.com/drhuffman12/bench_vs/blob/master/threads/README.md ). (For simple calculations/transformations, the overhead of fibers/etc seem to not be worth it; but for more computationally-intensive code, like Fibinacci calcs, fibers w/ higher CRYSTAL_WORKERS values and `same_thread: false` seemed to potentially helpful.)

Comment: Maybe a better question for the [forum](https://forum.crystal-lang.org/). In fact we have an [existing discussion](https://forum.crystal-lang.org/t/multithreaded-crystal-initial-thoughts/1089) there about benchmarking the multithread support.

Answer (score 2):

There is no answer to this question. The number of workers greatly depends on the type of application and availability/management of resources on the runtime system.

Of course, when your system has more than 4 cores, you'd want a higher number in order to use more available computing power. But you don't necessarily want to saturate all cores, depending on what else is running on the system. Especially IO-bound applications won't necessarily benefit from having too many worker threads. So setting `CRYSTAL_WORKERS=$(nprocs)` is probably not a good idea.

`CRYSTAL_WORKERS=4` is just a default value, because there needs to be one. It's a pretty common default because a) it should provide a reasonable improvement over single-threaded execution and b) modern CPUs have typically at least 4 cores.

Whenever your deploying an application to a runtime system, you need to consider what is an appropriate worker number for this specific environment and configure it accordingly. Using a different default value won't help in any way.